# password with special characters in odbc connection string in R

Tags: r, shiny, odbc, database-connection, connection-string

Some of my shiny app users can not login to the database via app but they could from their windows machine via SQL management studio.
I'm using the `odbc` package to create the connection string like :

```
ch <- odbc::dbConnect(odbc(), DSN = "myDSN", 
                Database = "myDb", 
                Authentication = "ActivedirectoryPassword",
                encoding = "windows-1252",
                AutoTranslate="yes", 
                UID = usr, 
                PWD = pas)
```

I checked some of the users using crazy passwords with special character like :

```
"1c0d9a1138a[]bb#$2m9d445654_Ñ#)/f8"
```

How I should change the encoding that this kind of password can be passed to the connection string via `odbc` in R?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend preventing this in the first place instead of changing the encoding. Any time they set a non-standard English utf-8 character in the password, you should block them. For example

```r
# this will pass
stringr::str_detect("1c0d9a1138a[]bb#$2m9d445654_#)/f8", "[^ -~]", negate = TRUE)
#> [1] TRUE
# this will not
stringr::str_detect("1c0d9a1138a[]bb#$2m9d445654_Ñ#)/f8", "[^ -~]", negate = TRUE)
#> [1] FALSE
# this will not
utf8::utf8_valid("\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb8\x8a")
#> [1] FALSE
```

For users who already have this in the password, ask them to reset the password.

Changing the encoding for them is possible but not recommended. You can do things like

```r
stringi::stri_trans_general("1c0d9a1138a[]bb#$2m9d445654_Ñ#)/f8", "Latin-ASCII")
#> [1] "1c0d9a1138a[]bb#$2m9d445654_N#)/f8"
```

Another possible solution

```r
pass <- "设Ñ置"
(myencode <- charToRaw(pass))
#> [1] e8 ae be c3 91 e7 bd ae
paste0(myencode,collapse = "")
#> [1] "e8aebec391e7bdae"
```

The idea is you store this final encoded string as a password on the server instead of the original string. Every time you check the password, convert to this same format and send to the server to check.

or you can use hash, even wired strings can be hashed

```r
digest::digest("\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb8\x8a")
#> [1] "3cdc47bf5d525acc5880c6ff1fa0030c"
```